# Checking if a Value is between a set of range intervals

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of data in 3 columns. All of them are depths in meters.
In Columns A and B I have ranges intervals, Column A being "From" and Column B "To ". Column C is a depth value.
I wanted to know if its possible to create a script that checks is the values on each cell in column C are between any of the range intervals in columns A and B.
If they are present put 1 in column D next to the value in column C. If not put 0.
Thanks for the help

Comment: *I wanted to know if its possible to create a script that...* - Yes! It's possible :)

Comment: vba is not necessary a simple formula will do it too.

Answer (score 1):

Formula in `D2`

```
=IF(AND(C2>=A2, C2<=B2),1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do this programmatically the following will work:

```
Sub checkvalues()
Dim comparea As Long
Dim compareb As Long
Dim comparec As Long


For i = 1 To 4
    comparea = Cells(i, 1).Value
    compareb = Cells(i, 2).Value
    comparec = Cells(i, 3).Value
    Cells(i, 4).Value = IIf(comparec >= comparea And comparec <= compareb, 1, 0)

Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: `Cells(i, 4).Value = IIf(comparec >= comparea And comparec <= compareb, 1, 0)`

Comment: Safer to use Long over Integer to avoid potential overflow.

Comment: This more or less does it, however I wanted to check if each value in column C is between any on the intervals in columns A-B. For example C4 has a value of 6, that number is between A3:B3 so it should be marked as 1. From what I can see this code only checks if its between the range in the same row. Hopefully is not that difficult to change. Thanks again